# Is there a macro to filter table by some list elements?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have a table with entries based on a list and I used a macro I found somewhere to be able to add/remove multiple elements from the list to one cell, let me show you an example:

```
TEST TABLE
test1
test1, test2
test1, test3
test2, test3, test4
```

Where items from the list are test1, test2, and so on.

Now I don't know if this is even possible, but I would like to be able to instantly filter the table by specific item from the list (for example test1), moreover I would like to put these criteria in a chceckbox filters so that instead of checkboxes like "test1, test2" in the checkboxes I would have only single items from the list (like test1, test2 and so on)

Is it even possible, and if yes can someone help to prepare a macro for this? In addition I am putting here my macro from the workbook:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim lUsed As Long
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
        lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
        If lUsed > 0 Then
            If Right(oldVal, Len(newVal)) = newVal Then
                Target.Value = Left(oldVal, Len(oldVal) - Len(newVal) - 2)
            Else
                Target.Value = Replace(oldVal, newVal & ", ", "")
            End If
        Else
            Target.Value = oldVal _
              & ", " & newVal
        End If

      End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

Call AutoFitColumns

End Sub

Sub AutoFitColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
rng.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be able to find info on using autofilter in vba, or you can use the macro recorder.  You would just need to use an array in your criteria that has all the text you want to filter for.  The following would filter for all names with pdf, doc or docx in the cell.  `Criteria1:=Array(".pdf", ".doc", ".docx"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: If you are using excel 2010, you can set up autofilter, and it has a new text box option to look for the text you want (instead of just having the text boxes). So you can now type test1 and filter to all cells that have test1 in them. If you wanted something a little more user friendly you could record yourself doing that then use the resulting macro to create the options you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old post, I'm providing one way of doing it, as a reference

- Create a new UserForm with default name "UserForm1"
- Create a new ComboBox with default name "ComboBox1" on the form, similar to this

[image]

---

Add this code to the VBA module for the Form:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private enableEvts As Boolean
Private thisCol As Range

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
   If enableEvts Then filterColumn thisCol, ComboBox1.Text
   'Me.Hide
End Sub

Public Sub setupList(ByRef col As Range)
   Set thisCol = col
   enableEvts = False
      setList col, ComboBox1
   enableEvts = True
   Me.Caption = "Filter Column: " & Left(col.Address(, False), 1)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   If KeyAscii = vbKeyEscape Then Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
   If Not Sheet1.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then Sheet1.UsedRange.AutoFilter
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
   Me.Hide
End Sub
```

---

Paste this code in the VBA module for Sheet1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   With Target
      If .CountLarge = 1 Then
         removeAllFilters Me
         If .Row = 1 Then
            .Offset(1, 0).Activate
            UserForm1.setupList Me.UsedRange.Columns(.Column)
            UserForm1.Show
         End If
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Sheet1 data:

[image]

---

Paste this code into a standard VBA module (open VBA: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>, click menu Insert > Module)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub setList(ByRef rng As Range, ByRef cmb As ComboBox)
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lst As Range, lr As Long

   If rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then
      xlEnabled False
      Set ws = rng.Parent
      removeAllFilters ws
      Set lst = ws.UsedRange.Columns(rng.Column)
      lr = getLastRow(lst, rng.Column)

      If lr > 1 Then
         With cmb
            .List = Split(getDistinct(lst, lr), ",")
            .ListIndex = -1
         End With
      End If
      xlEnabled True
   End If
End Sub

Public Sub xlEnabled(ByVal onOff As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = onOff
    Application.EnableEvents = onOff
End Sub

Private Function getLastRow(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal lc As Long) As Long
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long
   If Not rng Is Nothing Then
      Set ws = rng.Parent
      lr = ws.Cells(rng.Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, lc).End(xlUp).Row
      Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lc), ws.Cells(lr, lc)) 'updates rng (ByRef)
   End If
   getLastRow = lr
End Function
```

---

```
Private Function getDistinct(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal lr As Long) As String
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lst As String, lc As Long, tmp As Range, v As Variant, c As Double

   Set ws = rng.Parent
   lc = ws.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Set tmp = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lc + 1), ws.Cells(lr, lc + 1))

   If tmp.Count > 1 Then
      With tmp.Cells(1, 1)
         .Formula = "=Trim(" & ws.Cells(rng.Row, lc).Address(False, False) & ")"
         .AutoFill Destination:=tmp
      End With

      tmp.Value2 = tmp.Value2       'convert formulas to values
      tmp.Cells(1, 1).ClearContents 'remove header from list
      cleanCol tmp, lc
      lr = getLastRow(tmp, lc + 1)

      lst = Join(Application.Transpose(tmp), ",")
      lst = Replace(lst, ", ", ","):   lst = Replace(lst, " ,", ",")
      v = Application.Transpose(Split(lst, ","))

      lr = UBound(v)
      ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lc + 1), ws.Cells(lr, lc + 1)) = v
      getLastRow tmp, lc + 1

      cleanCol tmp, lc
      getLastRow tmp, lc + 1
      lst = Join(Application.Transpose(tmp), ",")
      lst = Replace(lst, ", ", ","):   lst = Replace(lst, " ,", ",")
      tmp.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Clear
   End If
   getDistinct = lst
End Function
```

---

```
Public Sub filterColumn(ByRef col As Range, ByVal fltrCriteria As String)
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lst As Range, lr As Long

   xlEnabled False
   Set ws = col.Parent
   Set lst = ws.UsedRange.Columns(col.Column)
   lr = getLastRow(lst, col.Column)

   lst.AutoFilter
   lst.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & fltrCriteria & "*"
   xlEnabled True
End Sub

Private Sub cleanCol(ByRef tmp As Range, ByVal lc As Long)
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long

   Set ws = tmp.Parent
   tmp.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
   lr = getLastRow(tmp, lc + 1)

   ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Cells(lr + 1, lc + 1), Order:=xlAscending
   With ws.Sort
      .SetRange tmp
      .Header = xlNo
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .Apply
   End With
End Sub

Public Sub removeAllFilters(ByRef ws As Worksheet)

   If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
   ws.Rows.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

---

Clicking on the header column ("TEST TABLE") will filter the list in 2 parts

Part 1:

- Extract the items from all cells of the current column into the first unused column of the sheet
- Trim all items, using Excel TRIM() formula (not copy-past using the clipboard)
- Remove duplicates from the list: `.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo`
- Sort the items in place (words in each cell are not separated yet)
- Create one string containing all text, separated by commas

Part 2:

- Split the string again
- Trim all items (cell words are now separated an can contain extra spaces)
- Remove duplicates from the list and sort them once more
- Create one final string containing the filtered list
- Update the combo box drop-down with final items

When the user selects an item from the drop-down list

- It will perform an Autofilter for cells containing partial text

  - `Criteria1:="*" & fltrCriteria & "*"`, (Ex **"*test3*"**)
- Button **Clear Sort** removes the Autofilter
- Button **Cancel** closes the form, without removing the filter
- Once the form is closed, the filter can be removed 3 ways

  - The standard way, using the Autofilter drop-down, and "Select All"
  - Menu **Data Tab** and clicking the **Filter** button
  - Clicking on the column header again (TEST TABLE)

---

Filtered drop-down list:

[image]

Filtered rows using criteria "test3"

[image]

Clear previous filter:

[image]